# jquery: Attach function to elements not yet loaded

Tags: jquery, event-handling

I attach a function to each th-element of a certain table:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#table_id thead th').each(function()
    {
       $(this).disableTextSelect(); // disableTextSelect() is user defined function extending jquery
    });
}
```

This works fine, if the table has already loaded.
In order to attach it to the table, if it will be loaded in the future I have to use .on(). But i don't know how :-(

```
$(document).on('which event?!', '#table_id thead th', function()
{
    $(this).disableTextSelect();
});
```

Thank you very much,
Phantom

Comment: how are you loading the table in the future? Register the events once it is loaded. you cant register events for things that don't exist yet.

Comment: @FlavorScape: I'm afraid that's entirely incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you want to bind the event to click?

```
$(document).on('click', '#table_id thead th', function() {
    $(this).disableTextSelect();
});
```

For future reference, the jQuery docs contain a list of all jQuery's events which can be found [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/).

Answer (score 1):

I met a same problem,and I used `.delegate("","load")`  but `delegate` can't bind future element with events `load,unload,change,blur,focus` because these events can't `bubble`,while `delegate`'s realization based on it.
Last I bind event with `click` and it's done.
If you REALLY need to bind `load` event, I think you can use `setInterval` instead:

```
var itv = setInterval(function(){
    var el = $("#table_id");
    if(el.length > 0){
        el.find('thead th').each(function(){
            $(this).disableTextSelect();
        });
        clearInterval(itv);
    }
},100);
```

May this will helpful to u. :)

Answer (score 0):

If the table is part of the page, it should be ready by the time of the ready event.

If you are loading the table by AJAX, then you should use the object returned from the `.ajax()` (or `.load()`, etc) and pass your logic to the `.success()` method on this object.

In theory, there is a load event, but it's not reliable though. In theory also, you can attach to the success of any AJAX request and then your function detaches itself when done, but this might be a bit nasty.

Answer (score 0):

I know something that will work, but I am not sure how feasible it is. Wrap what you want in a function.

```
function somename() {
  $('#table_id thead th').each(function()
    {
       $(this).disableTextSelect(); // disableTextSelect() is user defined function extending jquery
    });
}
```

call `somename()`  once to activate it for currently loaded elements, and call it each time you are loading new elements that will fit the selector. I know this will work, but I don't know effective it is to use it.